# Recursively copy file to its parent directory with parent directory name as prefix to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to copy specific files out of the current directory to the parent directory. The issue is all the files have same name, so I need to add prefix in a way the file will be identifiable after copying:

The directory structure-

- fs/sub-001/mri/brain.mgz
- fs/sub-002/mri/brain.mgz

What I want-

- fs/sub-001/sub-001_brain.mgz
- fs/sub-002/sub-002_brain.mgz

The 'mri' folder and its other contents can stay as is.

I tried:

```
find . -type f -name 'brain.mgz' -exec sh -c '
  for file; do
    parentdir=${file%/*}
    parentdir=${parentdir%/*}
    dirname=${parentdir##*/}
    cp "$file" "$parentdir/${dirname_file}${dirname}_${dirname_file}"
  done
' sh {} +
```

This partially does the job. It brings the file out to parent directory with the prefix but without file extention. So the result is-

- fs/sub-001/sub-001_

It looks like the file is being copied but without the original name and extension (without brain.mgz part) which defeats the purpose.

What am I doing wrong? I believe it has something to do with the 'cp' command in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
find . -type f -name 'brain.mgz' -exec sh -c '
for src; do
  dst=${src%/*/*}
  dst=$dst/${dst##*/}_${src##*/}
  echo cp "$src" "$dst"
done' sh {} +
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.